# pytesseract shows " 'str' object has no attribute 'save' " error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pytesser

when i run the following code for pytesseract

```
>>> import pytesseract
>>> import Image
>>> print pytesseract.image_to_string("plate.png")
```

it shows the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print pytesseract.image_to_string("plate.png")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 137, in image_to_string
    image.save(input_file_name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'
```

what does this error mean? How can i correct this?

thanks in advance

Comment: It means you're passing a string and not an Image object.

Comment: The title and the actual error message do not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an image object instead of file path (string):

```
import pytesseract
import Image

im = Image.open("plate.png")
print pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```